# Xcode 4.5 causing errors in iOS 5 apps

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, ios6

I having working on a timer application since last 3 to 4 months (when there was no sign of iOS 6) but due to some issues could not complete it. Now since the advent of iOS 6.. I am getting error in my code. I recently downloaded the xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 SDK (within it). Now when I run the app. It crashes on different occasions. Sometimes crashes right when it is started. Some times no crashes at all. 
Sometimes give me SGBRT error. Sometimes Bad_exc error(memory error). I don't know how to handle this. I have downloaded the iOS 5.1 simulator and on that when i run the app. No crashes at all but when I run the app on iOS 6 simulator. Wham! it crashes right away. 
I am in dire need of guidance. Anyone who has experienced the same error and got it troubleshoot please help me too. 
Thanks in Advance
Fahad. 
-   P.S. I added breakpoints to detect the errors and I was able to catch only one but could not understand why I got this error. Here is the code:

```
-(void) playAppSound:(NSString *) fName withExt:(NSString *) ext{
  NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : fName ofType :ext];
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath : path])
  {
      NSURL *pathURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fName withExtension:ext];
      // Instantiates the AVAudioPlayer object, initializing it with the sound
      if(self.appSoundPlayer)
      {
        if([self.appSoundPlayer isPlaying])
        {
            [self.appSoundPlayer stop];
            [self.appSoundPlayer release];
        }
      }
  //Thread breaks down in the next line self. appSoundPlayer...

    self.appSoundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: pathURL error: nil] ;

    //self.appSoundPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [appSoundPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [appSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    //[appSoundPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [appSoundPlayer play];
}
  else{
   //   NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", path);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Framework versions (SDK 5 <- wrong, SDK6 <-right)